# ngFor on keyValue with a mixture of string and number inputs causes focus to be lost when inputting a number

Tags: angular

I have an object with a few values of empty string and other values defaulted to 0.

Once I use `*ngFor` with the `keyValue` pipe and use `trackBy` to keep the dom from refreshing, I will still lose focus when inputting a new number value, but won't lose focus when inputting text.

Here is the stackblits https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ckzw9g?file=src/app/app.component.html where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can you elaborate it?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I would like to be able to input in the number field, without it losing focus of the input field, as I can only put one character before it loses focus and I have to re-select it. **But after reselecting the same input** the focus is then kept.

Comment: You can do one thing, you setFocus programatically when there is no input in input field, but will be on one input field. Is this what you want?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I would have to do that for each number input though? and this is affected with the text field, I can type without losing focus, but have to refocus just after the first input for number, I would also like to know if this is intended?

Comment: It is still unclear from the above statement. If you have 2 input fields at a time only one can be active on which user is typing and while user is typing it will remained focus. the other field can be populated, but can't be focused while you are typing in other input field

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara if you try to use the above stackBlitz and try to input into the number fields (the two in the middle) you can only ever put one character in before it loses focus. 

Here is an example, I select the field, which has a default value of 0, then I try to input the number 12, as soon as I select 1 the focus of that input field is lost, and I have to reselect it to input the 2

Comment: @noobcoder, check out my solution.

Comment: There is an issue with isNumber(val) method when you pass the data to this method when you type in it sends the string instead of number and because of this You are unable to write after any character entered. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah okay I see, I will try that and let you know tomorrow, didn't even realise that

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara but how come it starts working after the second focus on the input? surely it should do that with every character entered?

Comment: @noobcoder I have updated the solution in the answer. You can check.

Comment: You can also upvote it if it helps you resolve your question and query

Comment: I did upvote, but not enough rep for it to be visible.. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am answering it because you asked me, after debugging I figured out that will be beneficial for future reference:

1. For this code:

```
<input matInput *ngIf="isNumber(conf.value)" placeholder="Number" name="input{{conf.key}}"
    id="input{{conf.key}}" [(ngModel)]="inputs[conf.key]">
```

On the very first run this code will create the input text box because you are
passing 0 as number and ngIf will be true so it will create an input box.

2. When you input any value in the above text box "The inputted value will be a string" by default as no type is mentioned in the textbox, so the above text boxed will be removed and a new text box is created by angular the below one:

```
 <input matInput *ngIf="isString(conf.value)" placeholder="Text" name="input{{conf.key}}"
    id="input{{conf.key}}" [(ngModel)]="inputs[conf.key]">
```

This is because when the values of associated object changes, angular runs the change detection to update the view and find out the inputted value is string and creates a new textbox with that value as it is Ngmodeled and object work by reference(it is updating inputs object that is declared in the component) and when you enter the subsequent characters it allows you to keep it focused as long as it satisfy the if condition.

Note: if you add type="number"(that checks isNumber) in the input box, it will allow you to enter as many times you want and it will remained focus.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've implemented what you want at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-noj1gm?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: This is not what he is asking, but thats good you have made the changes.

Comment: That seems to work, I will refactor my code and use that, thanks, it isn't the way I wanted to do it, but allows it to be done, so will accept it as the answer thanks